# Create and delete a zip file

Tags: java, junit5

I wrote a JUnit 5 test and I need to create a zip file, put some text files on it and remove the zip file.

I don't have any problem for creating the zip file and the text files inside it, but whenever I call `file.delete()` it returns `false`.

I even tried to create an empty zip file and it also fails to delete it. Is there a way to solve this ?

```
    static File file;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp() throws IOException {

        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file=File.createTempFile("tempDir",".zip")));

        ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry("emptyFile.txt");
        out.putNextEntry(e);    
        out.closeEntry();    

        e = new ZipEntry("oneLineFile.txt");
        out.putNextEntry(e);

        StringBuilder sb;
        byte[] data;
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("route_id,agency_id,route_short_name,route_long_name,route_type");
        data = sb.toString().getBytes();
        out.write(data, 0, data.length);

        out.closeEntry();

        out.close();
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void set(){

        file.delete(); // return false

    }
```

Comment: Why not manually create the zip file and provide as a test resource instead, from an implementation POV?

Comment: @Compass Is it a good practice to do this for a JUnit test ? It's the first time I deal with JUnit testing and I thought about creating a zip file manually but I didn't know that it was acceptable

Comment: Yes. Sometimes if you need to process PDF/XML/JSON/XLS, it's easier to have a sample data ready. This also allows you to redo your tests rapidly without having to recompile the code, as it removes a code/library/package issue from scope.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't create too many temporary files use [`File.deleteOnExit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()):

> Requests that the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname be deleted when the virtual machine terminates. Files (or directories) are deleted in the reverse order that they are registered. Invoking this method to delete a file or directory that is already registered for deletion has no effect. Deletion will be attempted only for normal termination of the virtual machine, as defined by the Java Language Specification.

File system operations can be unsafe e.g. Windows likes to lock the files used by the JVM process.

Moreover your test code can terminate with exception without properly closing `ZipOutputStream` potentially locking the file and preventing deletion. You should use `finally`:

```
ZipOutputStream out = null;
try {
  out = ...
} finally {
  if (out != null) 
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I did what you said and put the finally statement, but now I'm geting "java.io.IOException: Stream closed" right after at this line "ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry("emptyFile.txt")". Is it normal ?

Comment: Instead of try-finally I would use try-with-resource. You get the same result but with less code: `try (ZipOutputStream out = new ...) { ... }`

Comment: @Robert you are right but depending on the library `ZipOutputStream` might not implement `AutoClosable`

Comment: Which common library does provide an non-auto-closeable `ZipOutputStream`? I only know the JRE implementation (and this one extends AutoCloseable).